# Convert Yards to Miles, Furlongs and Yards

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I'm trying to write a function that will take a parameter 'yards' and convert that parameter into Miles, Furlongs and Yards.

For example:

```
milesFurlongsYards(1760); // returns '1m'
milesFurlongsYards(2220); // returns '1m 2f'
milesFurlongsYards(2224); // returns '1m 2f 4y'
```

To help, there are 8 Furlongs in a Mile and 220 Yards in a Furlong.

Thanks for any help

Edit
I've tried to find the miles first, then using the remainder find the furlongs and then using the remainder of that find the yards but this isn't working for me. Code so far:

```
yardsToMilesAndFurlongsReadable(yards) {
        let miles = Math.floor(yards / mileToYard);
        let furlongs = (yards % mileToYard) / furlongToYard;
    }
```

Comment: How would you do that with pencil and paper?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please edit to include these details. Otherwise it reads as "write this code for me." And this also kind-of seems like a homework type of problem, especially where you're giving us hints about number of furlongs in a mile and number of yards in a furlong (which seems really odd: why do *we* need these hints if *you* are supposed to solve this?)

Comment: Right now this is a math problem, not a programming one.

Comment: I've updated the question with what I've tried and my code so far.

Comment: Even with your update: Show your output. "*this isn't working for me*" is vague: we have no idea how it's not working for you. Do you get output? (well, you don't, since you don't return any value, but what does the debugger tell you?)

Comment: posted solution bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, figured it out.

```
const furlongToYard = 220;
const mileToYard = 1760;

class Distance {

    yardsToMilesAndFurlongsReadable(yards) {
        let miles = Math.floor(yards / mileToYard);
        yards = yards % mileToYard;

        let furlongs = Math.floor(yards / furlongToYard);
        yards = yards % furlongToYard;

        return `${miles > 0 ? miles + 'm' : ''} ${furlongs > 0 ? furlongs + 'f' : ''} ${yards > 0 ? yards + 'y' : ''}`;
    }
}

export default Distance;
```